# Case-sensitive minif?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

how do i do a case sensitive minifs in excel/google sheets?

I have 2 columns, A is a list of dates, and B is a list of IDs. IDs are case sensitive. 
there could be multiple IDs associated with different dates, and I want to find the smallest dates.

My minif formula was minif(A:A,B:B,B2), how do I make it case-sensitive?

Comment: Have a look at `EXACT`. If I would write it out it would look like: `=MIN(IF(EXACT(B2,B:B),A:A,""))`.... Enter as array....However I hadn't tested since I'm not behind a pc.

Answer (score 1):

@JvdV formula works.

But there is another option without an array formula:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,(1/(EXACT(E2,B:B)))*A:A,1)
```

[image]